# DISK CRITICAL - /dev/xvda1 is not accessible: Permission denied

Tags: centos-7, monitoring, nagios

I've configured nagios to check status on specific server. Only the cpu status showing. TCP and Disk spaces are not showing. But in the when i check the status of Disk and TCP that shows result. Nagios server says CHECK_NRPE: Error receiving data from daemon.

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9IoS.png)

Answer (score 0):

change SELinux permissions to permissive and restart the nrpe.
check status getenforce
Then change to
/etc/selinux/config 
SELINUX=permissive